# Why left join show the error?

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

Is there is any error in the query i have given below.

```
SELECT * FROM employee Left JOIN bonus;
```

I have executed this using the sqlfiddle online. It shows me a error.

and also am facing the issue for full outer join.

```
SELECT * FROM   bonus  FULL OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.id=bonus.id;
```

Comment: What error gives you?

Comment: I have executed this query in online. In W3 schools its working fine. But it sqlfiddle it shows "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: select * from employee employee left join bonus"

Comment: @Mihai http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d359b/3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232515/1

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a join column when using a LEFT or RIGHT join. How are your Employee and Bonus tables related? If both tables contain an "EmployeeId" column for example, then you would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee LEFT JOIN bonus ON employee.EmployeeId = bonus.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Matching tables is an optional thing when you join them.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't notice the mysql tag. On MS SQL Server, using a LEFT JOIN without an ON clause would give you an error.

Comment: It happens sometimes :)

Comment: Actually, you are incorrect. When specifying LEFT or RIGHT, also in MySQL you must specify an ON or USING clause, according to the documentation, so I would prefer that you take back your downvote :-)

Comment: Yes @Dan Hope you was near to my problem. It was showing error in one environment. But works fine with other. Is mysql does not support it.

Comment: Are you sure? I can barely see that On is not required in documentation.

Comment: `join_condition` does not appear in square brackets in the documentation, when LEFT or RIGHT is used, meaning it is not optional.

Comment: Exactly, if you use `LEFT` or `RIGHT` you must specify a column to join with, else you will get an error. If you use `INNER` OR only `JOIN` statement the query will work

Comment: @Dan Then how the "SELECT * FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders;" in W3 try yourself works. It should show error but query is executed and result is shown.

Comment: @VinoDiary Good question. They must be using a different SQL dialect. I guess it will just do a cross join in this case, which is honestly confusing since you're specifying LEFT.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `ON`, all joins automatically become `CROSS JOIN`. You can try it with `CROSS JOIN`. Here is the mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: This is not true when using LEFT or RIGHT. In that case, you must specify an ON or USING clause, otherwise you get an error - also on MySQL (I just tested it using sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/14559)

Comment: @dan is using on clause is mandtory for inner and outer join. If not used it takes as an cross join. Is my understanding correct.

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

```
join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

In MySQL  the on is optional for join, but not for left outer join or right outer join.